# Transform data stored in a TIFF file to a CSV with latitude/longitude and data?

Tags: csv, latitude-longitude

I've obtained a population density map from the European commission's [Global Human Settlement Layer](http://ghsl.jrc.ec.europa.eu/index.php). The download contained a `.tif` file and `.tif.ovr` file sharing the same name. Their specifications say about the file *"Values are expressed as decimals (Float)
representing the absolute number of inhabitants of the cell."*

I need to convert this data to a format where it is listed, in plain text, the latitude, longitude, and that float value from earlier for every cell (csv would probably work best).

So what would be the best way to go about this conversion?

Sorry if this is rather basic or vague as I'm new to this field.

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: None yet, I was new to GIS and was wondering what software to use to accomplish this. Cheers.

Comment: For software recommendations there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange..  That site has put a lot of time into providing [asking guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336) to help the framing of such questions.

Comment: Given how domain specific this problem is, it feels inappropriate to go to a generalized forum like that. Even a link to a reference pdf on the standards to allow me to write my own conversion code would have been enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the `gdal` utilities installed, you can do this at the command line, using `gdal_translate` to convert to `XYZ` format. This is a flavour of CSV using spaces to separate the three columns:

Initial file:

```
$ file /tmp/r.tif
/tmp/r.tif: TIFF image data....
```

Convert:

```
$ gdal_translate -of XYZ /tmp/r.tif /tmp/r.xyz
Input file size is 360, 180
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

Looks like:

```
$ head /tmp/r.xyz
-179.5 89.5 0.493539184331893921
-178.5 89.5 0.505515038967132568
-177.5 89.5 0.181563228368759155
-176.5 89.5 0.76950681209564209
```

Using the TIF from here: http://cidportal.jrc.ec.europa.eu/ftp/jrc-opendata/GHSL/GHS_POP_GPW4_GLOBE_R2015A/GHS_POP_GPW42015_GLOBE_R2015A_54009_1k/V1-0/ the output is in the coordinate system of the raster, which in this case is a Mollweide world projection, the first few lines looking like this:

```
-17619094.5474435315 8750529.46186848916 0
-17618094.5474435315 8750529.46186848916 0
-17617094.5474435315 8750529.46186848916 0
-17616094.5474435315 8750529.46186848916 0
```

To convert this to lat-long, use `cs2cs` and specify the coordinate system:

```
cs2cs  -f %.6f +proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs < out.csv | out_ll.csv
```

The first few lines of `out_ll.csv` are:

```
-2147483648d-2147483648'-nan"E  -2147483648d-2147483648'-nan"N 0.000
-2147483648d-2147483648'-nan"E  -2147483648d-2147483648'-nan"N 0.000
-2147483648d-2147483648'-nan"E  -2147483648d-2147483648'-nan"N 0.000
-2147483648d-2147483648'-nan"E  -2147483648d-2147483648'-nan"N 0.000
-2147483648d-2147483648'-nan"E  -2147483648d-2147483648'-nan"N 0.000
```

this is basically junk because the Mollweide projection turns the globe into an oval, and the raster is rectangular, so there's a load of non-projectable cells in the corners. Further on it gets okay, looking a bit like this (I put in some fake population data in my test to check it was working):

```
-177.413720 83.630801 30.000000
-177.372595 83.630801 40.000000
-177.331471 83.630801 20.000000
-177.290347 83.630801 40.000000
-177.249223 83.630801 50.000000
-177.208098 83.630801 60.000000
```

Note this is no longer a regular grid in lat-long.

I've not tested this on the whole raster because its 540 million points and I'm not even sure that's the file you want because you didn't point to a specific example...

Comment: Sorry, this results in six or seven digit numbers (before the decimal place) for the first two columns. How would I convert this to lat/long coordinates?

Comment: As an example 17874905.452556469 -1009470.5381315108 0